# is there any method or function to extract only URL's from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with one column name as replies which has below contents

ljaganathan:https://engineering.paypalcorp.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=CAL&amp;title=Report+REST+Interface
vanbalagan:Please refer: https://engineering.paypalcorp.com/confluence/display/GPS/User+Guide+for+Self-serve+Alerts

i want to extract only the URL's from that specific column which has only URL's
tried with below code

```
   import re 
   re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', df['replies'])
```

got this error
**TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

even tried with this

```
df["replies"]=df["replies"].astype(str)
pattern = r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)'

df['links'] = ''
df['links']= df["replies"].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)

print(df['links')
```

getting NaN values for the above one

Can some onehelp me with the above one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is not correct. Can you try:

```
import re 
re.findall('(https?:\/\/\S+)', df['replies'])
```

or your second version:

```
df["replies"]=df["replies"].astype(str)
pattern = '(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*)'

df['links'] = ''
df['links']= df["replies"].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)

print(df['links')
```

There are online testers to test your regular expression that are very useful in debugging, like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I was able to do this with second one .. but did get the same error with first one though.which is TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
thanks :@Niels Henkens

Comment: still dont understand why am i not able to do this with re.findall

Comment: if i have to extract only those URL which has the word confluence in it then .. what is the change i need to make